# Why is 'reorder_uefi: False' being ignored in Ubuntu autoinstall cloud-config?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a cloud-config file `/tftp/user-data` which contains the following:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
...content removed...
storage:
  grub:
    reorder_uefi: False
  layout:
    name: direct
```

However, every time this runs, it re-orders UEFI boot order and puts the PXE boot interface at the top, so it stays in a constant boot loop and never boots into the installed OS unless I interrupt, go into the System Settings and change the boot order back once it has rebooted after installation.  I guess this is curtin doing it (like it does with MAAS, where it makes sense) but I can't work out why this is being ignored, or how I can stop it.

I'm using the boot files from Ubuntu 20.04.3 - am I doing something wrong in the cloud-config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `layout` option does not work with custom `grub` settings.  The [installer code appears to only use](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/9818ca97177e69add8c8e4d549c7f14026c11981/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py#L432) the `grub` configuration when `layout` is **not** used.  You can try submitting a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity if you think that is the wrong behavior.

**Testing** - using Ubuntu 20.04.3 (`subiquity 21.08.2`).

Using this configuration in `user-data`

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
...
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
```

generated this line in `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf` without the `reorder_uefi` option.

```
grub: {probe_additional_os: true, terminal: unmodified}
```

Using this configuration in `user-data`

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
...
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-sda1}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-sda1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: linux, number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda2}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-sda2, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, flag: linux, number: 3, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda3}
    - name: vg-0
      devices: [partition-sda3]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm-volgroup-vg-0
    - {name: lv-root, volgroup: lvm-volgroup-vg-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm-partition-lv-root}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm-partition-lv-root, preserve: false, type: format,
      id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-2}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-2, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-3}
```

generated this line in `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf`.

```
grub: {probe_additional_os: true, reorder_uefi: false, terminal: unmodified}
```

**how it works**

As part of the install, the server live-installer (*subiquity*) will generate a config for *curtin*(`/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf`) and run *curtin*.  It is *curtin* that actually performs the disk partitioning (and many other steps).  Part of the *curtin* config is the `storage` section.  This is very similar to the `storage` section provided in the autoinstall file, but *subiquity* adds some additional features beyond what *curtin* supports.  The `layout` option is one of these features.  When `layout` is used, *subiquity* programmatically generates the *curtin* `storage` config and ignores the other user provided settings.

Comment: Many thanks, if only to point me at the generated config location!