# What's wrong with my autoinstallation for ubuntu server 22.04.1?

Tags: server, 22.04, user-data

I'm trying to create an auto installation for an ubuntu 22.04.1. But every time I try to boot after some point its restarting and it never stops. There is no Error message and I don’t know what's wrong. The user-data file looks as following:

```
#cloud-config

autoinstall:

  apt:

    disable_components: []

    geoip: true

    preserve_sources_list: false

    primary:

    - arches:

      - amd64

      - i386

      uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

    - arches:

      - default

      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports

  identity:

    hostname: edgedevice

    password: $6$xU$HazGI4kXe7UxWc9xpP1rGRQsCc1d7a488fYeVvpw0pkkV3lWnNduZw17D7yGqcxS5cwgb49/W3PM7Kxq1BSSS/

    realname: edgeconnector

    username: ec

  kernel:

    package: linux-generic

  keyboard:

    layout: ch

    toggle: null

    variant: de_sundeadkeys

  locale: en_US.UTF-8

  network:

    ethernets:

      enp1s0:

        dhcp4: true

      enp2s0:

        dhcp4: true

    version: 2

  ssh:

    allow-pw: true

    authorized-keys: []

    install-server: false

  storage:

    layout:

      name: direct
    
  updates: security

  version: 1
```

To create an new autoinstall iso i used [this](https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator/pull/33) auto-install-generator.

If i change the storage configuration to the following i get the error "autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition"

```
  storage:

    config:

    - ptable: gpt

      serial: mSATA_mini_3ME3_BCA12102030330005

      wwn: '0x524693f2ca251959'

      path: /dev/sda

      wipe: superblock

      preserve: false

      name: ''

      grub_device: false

      type: disk

      id: disk-sda

    - device: disk-sda

      size: 1127219200

      wipe: superblock

      flag: boot

      number: 1

      preserve: false

      grub_device: true

      type: partition

      id: partition-0

    - fstype: fat32

      volume: partition-0

      preserve: false

      type: format

      id: format-0

    - device: disk-sda

      size: 4294967296

      wipe: superblock

      flag: swap

      number: 2

      preserve: false

      grub_device: false

      type: partition

      id: partition-1

    - fstype: swap

      volume: partition-1

      preserve: false

      type: format

      id: format-1

    - path: ''

      device: format-1

      type: mount

      id: mount-1

    - device: disk-sda

      size: 26591887360

      wipe: superblock

      flag: ''

      number: 3

      preserve: false

      grub_device: false

      type: partition

      id: partition-2

    - fstype: ext4

      volume: partition-2

      preserve: false

      type: format

      id: format-2

    - path: /

      device: format-2

      type: mount

      id: mount-2

    - path: /boot/efi

      device: format-0

      type: mount

      id: mount-0

    swap:

      swap: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile I managed to solve the problem.
First of all if you have a similar problem boot it with UEFI then the error "autoinstall config did not create needed partition" won't be present. And second like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389303/1624140) if you add grub: reorder_uefi: False for me it stopped with the endless rebooting.