# How to prevent subiquity from modifying the boot device order?

Tags: boot, subiquity

When performing an autoinstall via network, the install target device is set to be the primary boot device (which is arguably reasonable in most cases).  Is it possible to prevent changes to the boot order during an autoinstall?  I've see references to an undocumented(?) "reorder_uefi" option which does not seem to work for me, and a curtin "update_nvram" option, but I don't see that in a fresh checkout of subiquity.

Ubuntu 20.04.4

This is the `user-data` that I tried:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "...encrypted password..."
    username: ubuntu
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    allow-pw: true
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: false
```

Looking at recent code, I think that `grub` is changing the boot order, and grub *can* be told not to do that via `--no-nvram`, but that option does not appear to be used in any cases in subiquity.

Comment: A workaround: You can enter UEFI and change them back.

Comment: What specific Ubuntu release are you booting?  What is your `user-data` file content?  My first guess is you are using the `storage` `layout` option which is incompatible with settings under `grub` (like https://askubuntu.com/a/1378297/376778)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @AndrewLowther: I updated the original post with Ubuntu version, `user-data` example, and some additional information on `grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, it looks like you need a `config` section under `storage`.  The `grub` section is only included if there is a `config` section.

The [source code](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/9818ca97177e69add8c8e4d549c7f14026c11981/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py#L442)

```
        elif 'config' in self.ai_data:
            self.model.apply_autoinstall_config(self.ai_data['config'])
            self.model.grub = self.ai_data.get('grub')
            self.model.swap = self.ai_data.get('swap')
```